# How to create captcha in web api which renders in client?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, captcha

I need to implement server side captcha in web api. Angular 4 is my front end.
What i need is catcha generate and validate in server side using sql server(for storing captcha for validtion) and render captcha in client side.

Is there any open source library available for that?

I used SuperNova 3.0.9 but it uses its own sql lite db for verification and i couldn't override the functionality.